# Crop large raster in network drive

Tags: r, image, gis, r-raster

Is it possible to use R to crop out a subsection from a raster currently stored on a network drive without the need to download the file to the local drive first?

It is possible to read a raster from a network drive using the call:

```
img <- raster("Z:/path/file.bsq")
```

However, the raster I am working with exceeds the file size limit of my network drive. I would have thought that because raster() does not actually read the entire file into memory it should be possible to just read in the metadata and then use:

```
img_crop <- crop(x=img, y=extent)
```

To read in a cropped part of the image into the memory. Of course, this fails at the stage of reading the raster so I can't even try and crop it. I guess that crop has no reason to know in advance how large the cropped raster will be, which is part of the reason this doesn't work.

Is there a way of doing this or do I just need to increase the file size limit of my network drive?

Comment: So where is the raster right now if you can't store it on you network drive? I would use `gdalwarp` to crop the dataset prior to loading it into R. You can download it [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries).

Comment: It's stored on a server and I can download it manually. But I can't access it through WebDav (the network drive manager) because my registry won't let me open files greater than 500MB through the network drive.

Comment: You could try to build a gdal `vrt` virtual file for a subset of your file using `gdalbuildvrt` from `gdalUtils` using the `te` parameter, and then `writeRaster` to save the `vrt` file. (Don't know if it will work, though - depends if building the `vrt` and then saving it is "seen" by your system as an "open" operation.)

Comment: Good suggestion @LoBu got a feeling it will have the same problem as raster but I might give it a go. TBH I'm coming round to the idea that I just need a better network drive solution. Just seems such a waste to have to download hundreds of GBs when all I need are a few MBs.